# Does Ubuntu 10.x run well on MacBook aluminum/air models? What are the issues?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, macbook-air, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu on my MacBook about 2 years ago, and although most things worked, I had trouble with the trackpad (felt very jerky and two-finger tap didn't work), as well as with WiFi and Bluetooth.

What's the current state of Ubuntu?

Have these issues been resolved yet?

Comment: It may be helpful to modify your question to better focus on whether those specific issues are present. It's much easier to say "this, this, and this issue isn't present" than "there are no issues" or the subjective "you won't have trouble with it anymore". Perhaps title the question, **"Does the latest Ubuntu version have any known hardware problems on MacBook aluminum/air models?"** or **"Do trackpad, Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth work in the latest Ubuntu version on MacBook aluminum/air models?"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havnt had any issues, ive run it on a macbook pro and a powerbook.
The easiest way to check is to just use a live disk for a little while.

But as far as i know there arnt too many bugs..